# displaying dynamic pieCharts via javaScript(only the last one in for loop is displayed)

Tags: javascript, pie-chart

**i am having trouble displaying all charts in for loop only the last one is displayed**

```
var l = 0;
for (j in quizs[i].quests) {
  if (val == quizs[i].quests[j]["quizId"]) {
    l = l + 1;

    $(function() {
        console.log(quizs[i].quests[j]["question"]);

        var a = '#' + l;

        var pieChartCanvas = $(a).get(0).getContext('2d');
        var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);
        var PieData = [];
        for (var b in quizs[i].quests[j].reps) {
            if (quizs[i].quests[j]['questId'] == quizs[i].quests[j].reps[b]["quest"]) {
                PieData.push({
                    value: quizs[i].quests[j].reps[b]["stat"],
                    startAngle: 240,
                    color: hex(),
                    label: quizs[i].quests[j].reps[b]["rep"]
                });
            }
        }
        var pieOptions = {

            segmentShowStroke: true,
            segmentStrokeColor: '#fff',
            segmentStrokeWidth: 1,
            percentageInnerCutout: 0,
            animationSteps: 100,
            animationEasing: 'easeInSine',
            animateRotate: true,
            animateScale: false,
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: true

        };
        pieChart.Doughnut(PieData, pieOptions);
    });
}}
```

i know the problem is with function and for loop but i don't know exactly what, any help is appreciated

Comment: Please properly indent your code. As it is now, your code is utterly unreadable.

Comment: thank you for replying,i changed it

Comment: Replace you `var` declarations by `let` and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Especially replace `var pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);` by `let pieChart = new Chart(pieChartCanvas);`.

Comment: i tried but nthg changed

Comment: even in the second loop only the last reponses are displayed in the chart

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve